# error '1004': Select method of Range class failed

Tags: vba, excel, listbox

I am sure that every person who reads the title would say "oh no, not again". But before posting this, I have read about 7-8 previous questions with similar title and no-one seemed to work. So this is the deal:

My workbook uses the `Workbook_Open` event to show a userform:

```
Sub Workbook_Open()
    UserForm1.Show
End Sub
```

`Userform1` includes a textbox and a listbox. The listbox is populated with data dynamically, according to user's typing in the textbox. So far everything ok.

When user clicks at a value inside the listbox, I want a specific cell to be selected. So I used this:

```
Private Sub ListBox1_Click()
    Dim Cell As Range

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1)
        Set Cell = .Range("C3", .Cells(.Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp)).Find(UserForm1.ListBox1.Text, LookIn:=xlValues)
        .Range(Cell, Cell.Offset(0, 2)).Select
    End With
End Sub
```

But as many others before me, I cannot make `Select` work properly and this code gave an error like the title.

I tried several things to make this code work.

-Tried `Application.GoTo`, using it instead of `Select`,as someone suggested.

-Tried to move the code of the `ListBox1_Click` event to a sub inside a standard module and call this sub with the `ListBox1_Click` event.

-Tried to select the worksheet first as others suggested.

-Tried `Worksheets(1).Visible = True` as someone else suggested.

-Tried to activate the main window of the application first with `AppActivate Application.Caption`.

-Tried to scroll to the desired cell instead of selecting:

```
Private Sub ListBox1_Click()
    Dim foundRow As Integer

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1)
        foundRow = .Range("C3", .Cells(.Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp)).Find(UserForm1.ListBox1.Text, LookIn:=xlValues).Row
    End With
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = foundRow - 1
End Sub
```

I also tried other less important changes but I'm stuck with it. The funny thing is that before using the `Workbook_Open` event, I had `UserForm1` shown via a macro assigned to a button/shape in the worksheet and everything worked fine then.

Does anybody know how am I going to make `Select` work in my case?

On the other hand, it's well understood that `Select` causes a great deal of problems, so I'm not stuck with it. If anyone has a another way to have the same result I'm all ears.

Comment: I will bet that `Cell` is nothing.

Comment: Has the value been found leading to cell being a range.  Put a break point on the troublesome line and see if Cell is nothing

Comment: `If Not Cell Is Nothing then .Range(Cell, Cell.Offset(0, 2)).Select else msgbox "Didn't find the cell value!" End If`

Comment: Cell was not nothing. I picked a value existing for sure. Thanks for your tips.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to replicate the issue, first of all I followed what you described, made a list and picked from it to see if would scroll into view, and it worked.

If I closed the form, changed the active sheet. and then run the form it failed with the error message you are seeing.

Trying a number of things I discovered you can't select a cell if it is not the active sheet (which is logical, a user can not click on a cell that is not on the sheet they are viewing)

The below `Activate` line should fix it.

```
Private Sub ListBox1_Click()
    Dim Cell As Range

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1)
        Set Cell = .Range("C3", .Cells(.Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp)).Find(UserForm1.ListBox1.Text, LookIn:=xlValues)

        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Activate

        .Range(Cell, Cell.Offset(0, 2)).Select
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: so simple as that. thank you very much for your time. worked perfect.

Answer (score 0):

As noted by @ScotCraner and as [shown in the sample code on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839746.aspx) you should first check if something has been found before using / showing it.

The following should work flawlessly:

```
Private Sub ListBox1_Click()

    Dim Cell As Range
    Application.DisplayStatusBar = True

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1)
        Set Cell = .Range("C3", .Cells(.Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp)).Find(UserForm1.ListBox1.Text, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)
        If Not Cell Is Nothing Then
            Application.StatusBar = "Found " & UserForm1.ListBox1.Text
            .Activate
            .Range(Cell, Cell.Offset(0, 2)).Select
        Else
            Application.StatusBar = "Couldn't find " & UserForm1.ListBox1.Text
        End If
    End With

End Sub
```

Note, that you are using `UserForm1.ListBox1.Text` which does not consider `UserForm1.ListBox1.MultiSelect`.

Comment: Thanks for your very apt tip!
In this case I just thought I should choose a value that existed for sure in my sheet to see if this works.
In any case, it's better to implement this cheking in my code.